# How are demons compared to angels?

Tags: vertigo-comics, lucifer-2016

In the TV series (1st season) Maze and Amenadiel have a slight confrontation and he seems to not take her for a real threat. His talks seem to indicate that the threat a demon could be for an angel is....laughable at best.

So I'm wondering how are the two "species" in terms of power level? Are the angels really that far above demons as indicated there? Or is it more a similar power level only that one angel is VERY powerful?

Comment: http://lucifer.wikia.com/wiki/Angel

Answer (score 2):

In the Lucifer wiki you can read in the paragraph on Weaknesses:

> Supernatural Beings: Supernatural beings (i.e. gods, demons and other angels are able to cause physical harm to each other. Gods are capable of easily overpowering and destroying angels.

And in the same wiki in the Demon page it says:

> Unlike angels, demons don't have any specific weaknesses to kill them. In "Who's da New King of Hell?", Lucifer tells Chloe that demons are killable "it just takes a little extra oomph." During the fight with the demons brought to Earth by Eve, several are killed by powerful blows alone and one is killed by Eve shoving a high heel through her eye. However, it might vary between different demons, as Mazikeen, a particularly powerful demon, has never shown any fear of mundane weapons, and generally refers to the idea humans can harm her in amusement.

Demons do not have So I would say that **Demons can be killed by anything** as long as it is strong enough, while **Angels can only be killed by specific weapons**.

This is confirmed here in the powers section of the angel page in the wiki:

> Nigh-Invulnerability: Angels are nearly indestructible, and can withstand a vast amounts of physical damage, though they can be harmed, but very little. Bullets and knives bounce harmlessly off of their bodies, they are immune to all non-supernatural weapons, bombs, and objects, they are also immune to drowning, suffocation, extreme heat/cold, fire, choking, toxins, poisons, illnesses, radiation, sicknesses, viruses, and diseases. The only things that can kill an angel is the Flaming Sword and Demon daggers forged in Hell.